# Moving Between One Form to Another - C#

Tags: c#, methods, load, transition

I am currently creating a video game and coding the movement in a house between upstairs and downstairs.  I'm using PictureBoxes in combination with an IntersectWith event to transition between forms.

Transition Code to go Upstairs:

```
if(picPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picUpstairsTransition.Bounds))
            {
                MapFrmHouseUpstairs upstairs = new MapFrmHouseUpstairs();
                this.Hide();
                upstairs.ShowDialog();
            }
```

Transition Code to Go Back Downstairs:

```
if(picPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picGoDownstairs.Bounds))
        {
            MapFrmHouse goDownstairs = new MapFrmHouse();
            this.Hide();
            goDownstairs.ShowDialog();
            picPlayer.Location = new Point(497, 103);
        }
```

The issue I have is that when the player enters the house, he starts at the front.  When he tries to come back from upstairs, the character is moved back to the front instead of the base of the stairs.  Is there anyway I could create a method within MapFrmHouse such as:

```
public void fromDownstairs{picPlayer.Location = new Point(x,y);}
```

And call it when going downstairs?

Comment: Sure there is. Just put the things in the constructor and go from there, if you really want to use separate forms for this.

Comment: In the constructor, do you mean putting in MapFrmHouse(MethodInvoker) because that brings up an error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'd better use a game engine to design games like Unity which is much easier and more fun. This might be a learning task for you though which I don't blame :)

You can send information between forms in Windows Forms in many ways, two of which seems to fulfill your needs:

1. Using a higher level modifier for objects
2. Initializing values in constructors

To do the first you set the modifier property of the picture box called `picPlayer` in your `MapFrmHouse` class from `private` to `public` then you can do exactly what you mentioned:

```
if(picPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picGoDownstairs.Bounds))
{
    MapFrmHouse goDownstairs = new MapFrmHouse()
    {
        picPlayer.Location = new Point(x,y);
    };
    this.Hide();
    goDownstairs.ShowDialog();
}
```

For the second method you should create an overload constructor in your `MapFrmHouse` and accept a `Point` value in it and then set it your value like this:

```
public MapFrmHouse(Point p)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    picPlayer.Location = p;
}
```

And then use it in your code like this:

```
if(picPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picGoDownstairs.Bounds))
{
    MapFrmHouse goDownstairs = new MapFrmHouse(new Point(x,y));
    this.Hide();
    goDownstairs.ShowDialog();
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: The first solution still places my character at the front of the house.  I've made sure to make picPlayer a public modifier.  Is there anything else that could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe you set it again in a different location. Pause execution and step through your code to see if you set it again.